# MongoDB - How to aggregate data for each record

Tags: python, mongodb, django-rest-framework, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have some stored data like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "serverAddresses" : {
        "name" : "0.0.0.0:8000",
        "name2": "0.0.0.0:8001"
    }
}
```

I need aggregated data to this:

```
[
  {
    "gameId": "1",
    "name": "name1",
    "url": "0.0.0.0:8000"
  },
  {
    "gameId": "1",
    "name": "name2",
    "url": "0.0.0.0:8001"
  }
]
```

What is the solution without using for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$project` - Add `addresses` field by converting `$serverAddress` to (key-value) array.
2. `$unwind` - Descontruct `addresses` field to multiple documents.
3. `$replaceRoot` - Decorate the output document based on (2).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "addresses": {
        "$objectToArray": "$serverAddresses"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$addresses"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        gameId: "$_id",
        name: "$addresses.k",
        address: "$addresses.v"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4LqjgeXrR7a)